# ¿Cómo puedo guardar en una carpeta concreta plots y arrays en python?

Tags: python

hace un par de días que he empezado a hacer cosillas en Python, así que tengo más bien poca idea de las opciones que ofrece.
Estoy intentando que los plots y arrays que creo se guarden en una carpeta concreta, y no donde está guardado el script.
Estoy usando los comandos np.savetxt y plt.savefig, pero no encuentro la forma de especificar dónde quiero que se guarden =(
Si alguien sabe cómo hacerlo sería genial
¡Gracias!

def representar_reflectancia():

```
folder = folderPath.get()
folder_list = os.listdir(folder + "/")

for filename in folder_list:
    
    sub_folder = filename
    list_main = os.listdir(folder + "/" + sub_folder + "/") 
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
    plt.ylabel('R(%)')
    plt.ylim(0, 110)
    plt.xlim(400, 975)
    plt.title(sub_folder)
    
    **#quiero crear el directorio y guardar en él: os.mkdir(sub_folder)**
    
    
    for filename in list_main:
        
        try:
            wavel, R = np.loadtxt(folder + "/" + sub_folder + "/" + filename, delimiter='   ', usecols=(0,1), unpack=True, skiprows=14)
            Rnorm=R*0.99*factor
            plt.plot(wavel, Rnorm, label=filename)
            plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1),fontsize="x-small")
            global datos
            datos[:,0]=wavel
            datos[:,1]=Rnorm

            **np.savetxt("Normalized " + filename, datos, delimiter='   ')**             
        except:
            print(folder + "/" + sub_folder + "/" + filename + ' No tiene datos en el formato correcto')  
    
    **plt.savefig(sub_folder + '.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")**
    plt.show()
 
window.destroy()
```

folderPath = StringVar()

Comment: Probaste colocar el path del archivo a la izquierda de su nombre? Por ejemplo si tienes el path `c:/programa/arrays` donde guardarás tus arrays, probaste con poner `c:/programa/arrays/tuarray.txt`?

Comment: También puedes usar paths relativos, como por ejemplo si tu directorio de trabajo (generalmente el directorio de trabajo es donde está tu programa) es `c:/programa/` podrías poner `arrays/tuarray.txt` y el path se completará automaticamente.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por contestar. Estoy intentando saber cómo implementar lo que me dices. Así es como está:
   np.savetxt("Normalized " + filename, datos, delimiter=' ')                     
   plt.savefig(sub_folder + '.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches="tight")    
Te refieres a que ponga algo tipo:

Comment: Hola! De nada c: Antes de que comentes con código, el código no se ve bien en comentarios. Si quieres agregar información extra por favor edita la pregunta.

Comment: ya he visto...no me dejaba ni enviarlo jajaja voy a editar la pregunta, sí

Comment: No pasa nada c: os.listdir te devuelve el nombre de las carpetas y archivos, NO su path. Eso lo sabías?

Comment: @DanteS. Yo no :P

Comment: Sí, lo sabía jejeje como no tengo ni idea de que hace cada comando cada vez que voy a usar uno miro a ver qué tipo de cosa es y qué sale cuando lo usas. Al final he usado lo que me has dicho más o menos...                        np.savetxt(folder + "/" + sub_folder + "/" + "Normalized " + filename, datos, delimiter=' ')

Answer (score 0):

La forma para guardar un archivo de manera específica es la siguiente:

```
import os
archivo = 'array.txt'
filepath = os.path.expanduser(os.getenv('USERPROFILE'))+'\\Desktop'
```

Puedes crear la carpeta:

```
carpeta = 'plot'
nombre_carpeta = '{}\\{}'.format(filepath, carpeta)
os.mkdir(str(nombre_carpeta))
```

Y luego crear el archivo:

```
archivo = open(r'{}\{}'.format(nombre_carpeta, archivo), 'w')
print(r'{}\{}'.format(nombre_carpeta, archivo))
```

Si no te sirve, añade más información para poder ayudarte.
Saludos!

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Al final he utilizado una forma más simple, creo, pero muchísimas gracias por la intención :)